# Improper structure of SQL statement?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a DB with 4 tables: booking, hotel, guest and room. I'm trying to get my SQL statement (in Oracle) to produce the average room price of each hotel. This is currently what i have:

```
SELECT HOTEL.H_NAME "HOTEL NAME", ROUND(AVG (R_PRICE), 1) "AVERAGE ROOM PRICE"
FROM ROOM, HOTEL
WHERE HOTEL.H_NAME = 'Shangra_La'
OR HOTEL.H_NAME = 'Hilton'
OR HOTEL.H_NAME = 'Sheraton'
GROUP BY HOTEL.H_NAME
ORDER BY HOTEL.H_NAME;
```

From what I thought, that statement will select the hotel name and average price of all the rooms in the 'Shangra_la', 'Hilton' and 'Sheraton' and order them by the name of the hotel however when I do this, I get the same average for each hotel which is wrong. This is my output:

```
H_NAME      AVG. R_PRICE
Hilton      253.5
Shangra_La  253.5
Sheraton    253.5
```

Below is the table data for ROOM:

```
insert into room values
('1','H100','S',220.00);
insert into room values
('2','H100','D',230.00);
insert into room values
('3','H100','F',310.00);
insert into room values
('1','H200','S',260.00);
insert into room values
('2','H200','D',170.00);
insert into room values
('3','H200','S',250.00);
insert into room values
('4','H200','F',180.00);
insert into room values
('5','H200','F',295.00);
insert into room values
('1','H300','D',200.00);
insert into room values
('2','H300','S',420.00);
```

AND HOTEL:

```
insert into hotel values
('H100','Sheraton','Melbourne');
insert into hotel values
('H200','Shangra_La','Sydney');
insert into hotel values
('H300','Hilton', 'Perth');
```

Have I structured the statement incorrectly? What can I do to resolve this issue? Hopefully i have provided enough information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no join condition and it is therefore taking a cross product of `room` and `hotel`.

```
SELECT HOTEL.H_NAME "HOTEL NAME", ROUND(AVG (R_PRICE), 1) "AVERAGE ROOM PRICE"
FROM ROOM JOIN HOTEL ON HOTEL.HOTEL_NO = ROOM.HOTEL_NO
WHERE HOTEL.H_NAME = 'Shangra_La'
OR HOTEL.H_NAME = 'Hilton'
OR HOTEL.H_NAME = 'Sheraton'
GROUP BY HOTEL.H_NAME
ORDER BY HOTEL.H_NAME;
```

Comment: When I try this using HOTEL.HOTEL_NO = ROOM.HOTEL_NO it still gives me the same results, any other ideas?

Comment: Can you see what results you get if you do `SELECT *` without the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? You mean remove group by and order by and replace it with *?

Comment: Try to see the results for this query: `SELECT *
FROM ROOM JOIN HOTEL ON HOTEL.HOTEL_NO = ROOM.HOTEL_NO
WHERE HOTEL.H_NAME = 'Shangra_La'
OR HOTEL.H_NAME = 'Hilton'
OR HOTEL.H_NAME = 'Sheraton';`

Comment: YES thank you! I used what you initially said and it seemed to work you're the best thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to join the 2 tables together:

```
SELECT HOTEL.H_NAME "HOTEL NAME", ROUND(AVG (R_PRICE), 1) "AVERAGE ROOM PRICE"
FROM ROOM, HOTEL
WHERE HOTEL.H_NAME = 'Shangra_La'
OR HOTEL.H_NAME = 'Hilton'
OR HOTEL.H_NAME = 'Sheraton'
AND HOTEL.R_NUM = ROOM.R_NUM -- Here (guessing at your column names)
GROUP BY HOTEL.H_NAME
ORDER BY HOTEL.H_NAME;
```

edit:

```
SELECT H.H_NAME "HOTEL NAME", ROUND(AVG (R.R_PRICE), 1) "AVERAGE ROOM PRICE"
FROM ROOM R INNER JOIN HOTEL H ON R.HOTEL_NO = H.HOTEL_NO
WHERE H.H_NAME = 'Shangra_La'
OR H.H_NAME = 'Hilton'
OR H.H_NAME = 'Sheraton'
GROUP BY H.H_NAME
ORDER BY H.H_NAME;
```

otherwise the average number you see will be the average of the cartesian of all the rooms & prices

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to make a difference, could it be something in the average select statement?

Comment: ""HOTEL"."H_NAME": invalid identifier"

Comment: try my edit. Are you running this query direct on the database, or is there some post processing? Your results don't appear to match your query at all (e.g. column names are different)

Comment: maybe add your table structures to the question too..?

Answer (score 0):

I havent tested it but your first line should read something like this:

```
HOTEL.H_NAME "HOTEL NAME", ROUND(AVG (HOTEL.R_PRICE), 1)
```

I think you are averaging over all prices not the 
*hotel-specific*
 one.

Answer (score 0):

The query is missing one vital information: The link between `hotel` and `room`. The database doesn't know that `H100` is a hotel; you have to tell. This is called a "join" (since you join the two sets in a certain way).

Add `AND ROOM.R_HOTEL_ID = HOTEL.H_ID` to the `WHERE` clause (you will have to use the correct column names but you get the idea).

Comment: Okay thanks for the explanation, I tried this but it still gives me the same results: